# How set width border events with full calendar?

Tags: html, css, symfony, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm trying to have in my full calendar two kinds of events. I will differenciate them.

The color is not a good idea, because I need differte colors in thw two kinds of events. Il have thought about border color. But the propriety border color has a very little border. I want to set the border width bigger.

How can I do that?

I've tried in my main css:

```
.fc-event-inner {
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px;
}
```

But it does anything.

Thanks
Best regards

PS: I'm using fullcalendar with this symfony budle: https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle

Answer (score 2):

I use eventRender to handle them:

```
eventRender={info =>{
        info.el.style.borderWidth = '4px'
        info.el.style.borderRadius = '0px'                       
    }}
```

Comment: Can you add a short description?

Answer (score 1):

Just typing `.fc-event` didn't change border of events of Fullcalendar. So, I tried following code and it changed events border perfectly.

```css
.portlet.calendar .fc-event {
    border: 15px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change the width of the border by modifying the class fc-event:

```
.fc-event {
    border-width: 15px;
}
```

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vqs0r9jp/)

Answer (score 0):

Since **`fullcalendar` v5** there is no more `eventReader` callback.

Now you have to use the [event render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/event-render-hooks) eg. `eventDidMount`:

```js
eventDidMount: function(info) {
    info.el.style.borderRadius = '0px';
    info.el.style.borderWidth = '4px';
},
```

[image: screenshot evenDidMount style]